# SMOTE with more than 2 classes?

Tags: r, machine-learning, smote

I am working in R with a dataset of Olympic data that is very unbalanced and am looking for a way to balance the data appropriately.

After researching some, I found that ROSE works nicely, however, with only 2 classes. My output has 4 classes (Gold, Silver, Bronze, NoMedal) so ROSE will not work. I have been told to try and use the SMOTE function, however, I am uncertain how to use it when dealing with 4 classes. At the moment, my classes contain 13k Gold, 13K Silver, 13K Bronze, and 232K NoMedal.

Any ideas as to how I can use SMOTE to balance these 4 classes?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/UBL/versions/0.0.6/topics/SmoteClassif

Comment: Received this error message and not sure what it means

Comment: Error in neighbours(tgt, dat, dist, p, k) : 
  Can not compute Euclidean distance with nominal attributes!

Comment: Maybe this will help, but a full reproducible example would be better 
https://github.com/paobranco/UBL/issues/2

Comment: The link worked just fine... Solved it. Thank you!